# Django 2.1 Testcase Client getting unauthorized after logging in

Tags: django, unit-testing, pytest-django, django-2.1

I'm trying to upgrade my application from Django 1.11 to Django 2.1 and while I have been able to sort out most migrating issues, the API tests stopped working in the migration. After checking them, I see that I am getting a response with status code 401 (Unauthorized). I tried manually from the shell and this is what I get:

```
In [46]: from django.test import Client

In [47]: c = Client()

In [48]: user = User.objects.create(username='foobar')

In [49]: user.set_password('foobar')

In [50]: user.save()

In [51]: c.login(username=user.username, password='foobar')
Out[51]: True

In [52]: c.get('/me/')
Unauthorized: /me/
Out[52]: <Response status_code=401, "application/json">

In [53]: c.get('/me/').content
Unauthorized: /me/
Out[53]: b'{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}'
```

So, apparently, for some reason, my *Client* is logging in but it is not authorized, although in Django 1.11 it was working fine without any changes. The API and the App is still working fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your API use a cookie based auth or some sort of token based?

Comment: @xyres Right, I totally forgot about mentioning it. I use JWT tokens with `django-rest-framework-jwt`

Answer (score 0):

With django 2.1 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in settings.py is changed to MIDDLEWARE. Try to change it and it should work.

If you are looking for what else changed with django 2.1 I found this blog very useful: https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/django-version-20-a-few-key-features/